# Application Running as multiple processes

Tags: linux, memory, top

I have a java/tomcat application running on RedHat linux. Initially when I start the application, everything seems to be working perfectly fine. However, after some time, I guess 1-2 days, I witness the following as the top output.

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

7023 root      20   0 2857m 577m 5920 S  0.0 14.6   5:12.80 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp

17729 myus     20   0 2875m 574m 5920 S  0.0 14.5  10:49.76 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp

12597 root      20   0 2868m 564m 6304 S  0.0 14.3   5:54.86 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp

15863 myus     20   0 2856m 563m 5936 S  0.0 14.2  10:21.21 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp
```

I'm really confused as to how can my application be running 4 times. For what's worth, it is also taking up memory for all the 4 instances. Please shed some light on this mystery.

Answer (score 0):

It might have an auto restart jvm code in the app. I would look for the obvious places like crontab and also look why it is being launched under two users(this means that is being started from two places). If it is an internal application then you might also ask the dev as he can restart the application from the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could see the crontab of myuser and root with the `crontab -l` command. If there's nothing, maybe a postrotate section of a logrotate configuration is starting the new processes.